# Mingw static link libstdc++

Tags: linker, mingw, openmodelica

for work purpose I need to produce a shared library from a modelica file (.mo) and load in into matlab. But for some reasons, matlab uses a different version of libstdc++-6 that causes a conflict with the one needed by my shared library.

Here is the command line that I'm using to generate my .o files. The .mo file is previously transformed into c files.

```
gcc  -falign-functions -msse2 -mfpmath=sse   -Iinclude/ -Iinclude/fmi1 -I.    -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=GENROU -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o GENROU.o GENROU.c
```

A bunch of .o files are being genereted, and for reasons of brevity I will ommit the others, which are exactly the same.

And here is the problematic command line

```
g++ -shared -I. -o GENROU.dll GENROU_FMU.o  GENROU.o GENROU_functions.o GENROU_records.o GENROU_01exo.o GENROU_02nls.o GENROU_03lsy.o GENROU_04set.o GENROU_05evt.o GENROU_06inz.o GENROU_07dly.o GENROU_08bnd.o GENROU_09alg.o GENROU_10asr.o GENROU_11mix.o GENROU_12jac.o GENROU_13opt.o GENROU_14lnz.o GENROU_15syn.o GENROU_16dae.o GENROU_init_fmu.o  -Iinclude/ -Iinclude/fmi1 -I.    -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=GENROU -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0 -L"c:/users/simonz~1/appdata/local/temp/tmp7j8dix/GENROU/win_fmu"    -falign-functions -msse2 -mfpmath=sse  -L"C:/OpenModelica1.11.0-64bit//lib//omc" -Wl,-rpath,"C:/OpenModelica1.11.0-64bit//lib//omc" -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lregex -lexpat -lomcgc -lpthread -fopenmp -loleaut32 -lz -lhdf5  -lSimulationRuntimeC -lomcgc -lexpat -lregex -static-libgcc -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32 -lws2_32 -llis -lumfpack -lklu -lcolamd -lbtf -lamd -lsundials_idas -lsundials_kinsol -lsundials_nvecserial -lipopt -lcoinmumps -lpthread -lm -lgfortranbegin -lgfortran -lmingw32 -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -luser32 -lkernel32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lopenblas -lcminpack -lwsock32 -lstdc++  -llis -Wl,--kill-at
```

It leads to linker problem, where libstdc++ is defined twise, once in `libstdc++.a`, and the other in `libstdc++.dll.a`

```
C:/OpenModelica1.11.0-64bit/tools/msys/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0\libstdc++.a(fstream-inst.o):(.text$_ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEEC1Ev[_ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEEC1Ev]+0x0): multiple definition of `std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_filebuf()'

C:/OpenModelica1.11.0-64bit/tools/msys/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/libstdc++.dll.a(d002277.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here

C:/OpenModelica1.11.0-64bit/tools/msys/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0\libstdc++.a(fstream-inst.o):(.text$_ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5closeEv[_ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5closeEv]+0x0): multiple definition of `std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::close()'

C:/OpenModelica1.11.0-64bit/tools/msys/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/libstdc++.dll.a(d002264.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here

C:/OpenModelica1.11.0-64bit/tools/msys/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0\libstdc++.a(fstream-inst.o):(.text$_ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEED1Ev[_ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEED1Ev]+0x0): multiple definition of `std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_filebuf()'

C:/OpenModelica1.11.0-64bit/tools/msys/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/libstdc++.dll.a(d002281.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here

C:/OpenModelica1.11.0-64bit/tools/msys/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0\libstdc++.a(fstream-inst.o):(.text$_ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE4openEPKcSt13_Ios_Openmode[_ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE4openEPKcSt13_Ios_Openmode]+0x0): multiple definition of `std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode)'

[Several lines with the same 'multiple definition' omitted]

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Makefile:41: recipe for target 'GENROU_FMU' failed

mingw32-make: *** [GENROU_FMU] Error 1
```

I checked in the folder and both of the files are present. I don't know how they ended up there though.

Through the use of `OMShell.exe` I was able to get a few informations about what can be modified

```
getLinker()
"g++ -shared -Xlinker --export-all-symbols -fPIC"

setLinkerFlags("-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lregex -lexpat -lomcgc -lpthread -fopenmp -loleaut32 -lz -lhdf5")
true

getLinkerFlags()
"-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lregex -lexpat -lomcgc -lpthread -fopenmp -loleaut32 -lz -lhdf5"

getCompiler()
"gcc"

getCFlags()
"${SIM_OR_DYNLOAD_OPT_LEVEL} -falign-functions -msse2 -mfpmath=sse ${MODELICAUSERCFLAGS}"

getEnvironmentVar("SIM_OR_DYNLOAD_OPT_LEVEL")
""

getEnvironmentVar("MODELICAUSERCFLAGS")
""

getCXXCompiler()
"g++"

getCompileCommand()
"g++"
```

Comment: Why is `-lstdc++` in the command line as well, isn't that added by default? What happens if you remove it?

Comment: As I said, some part of the command line are generated by the tool, I don't have complete control over it. I will try today to have just the code generated to remove this flag and compile by hand

Answer (score 0):

You could try `buildModelFMU(..., fmuType="me", platforms={"static"})` to see if it works better, in particular if you change use `setLinker("gcc")` and `setLinkerFlags(...)`.

Otherwise, install a Linux VM (or the Ubuntu subsystem in Windows) and cross-compile using `platforms={"x86_64-w64-mingw32"}` (or i686 for 32-bit) which will use a different mingw GCC version.
The final link command for me using Linux uses regular GCC and no `-llibstd++`:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -shared -o M.dll M_FMU.o ... -flto -shared -static-libgcc -lm  -Wl,-Bstatic -lpthread -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

Comment: I tried the `buildModelFMU` function before, but no different output came out. Probably because of [this line](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OMCompiler/blob/e988ea489dc83b386647aa1d5237bfe8a61b48ae/Compiler/Script/CevalScriptBackend.mo#L3228). The output for in the question is comming from Windows 7, and I think it uses the mingw that is packaged with the installer. I'll give you a feedback after some tests, thanks

Comment: Also, how were you able to see the final link command if it compiled fine? I have no output whatsoever if everything runs fine

Comment: There is a config.log in the FMU. Running the same configure line and then "make" in the sources directory gives you the build log. It's not stored in the FMU (sadly).